# Dispose an object that is used in the constructer of another object

Tags: c#, .net, oop, dispose, using

I am using this code to read values from an isolated storage

```
        IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = null;
        StreamReader reader = null;
        IsolatedStorageFileStream isolatedStorageFileStream = null;
        String strIsolatedStorageValue = string.Empty;

        isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);

        try
        {
            isolatedStorageFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(strKey + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isoStore);
            // This code opens the store and reads the string.
            reader = new StreamReader(isolatedStorageFileStream);

            // Read a line from the file and add it to sb.
            strIsolatedStorageValue = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if (isolatedStorageFileStream != null)
            {
                isolatedStorageFileStream.Dispose();
            }
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Dispose();
            }
        }

        // Return the string.
        return strIsolatedStorageValue;
```

The problem is that when I am disposing isolatedStorageFileStream and then disposing the reader, visual studio tells me that isolatedStorageFileStream  could be disposed more than once! and when not disposing it I am getting the warning that isolatedStorageFileStream  should be disposed first.

What to do in such a case, that is disposing an object used in the constructor of another disposable object

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dispose the reader before the filestream.

To simplify your code, you should make use of  `using` blocks. They do the try/finally/dispose pattern automagically for you:

```
using (isolatedStorageFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(
          strKey + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isoStore)) {
    // This code opens the store and reads the string.
    using (reader = new StreamReader(isolatedStorageFileStream)) {
        strIsolatedStorageValue = reader.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :), but I am still gwetting the warning from visual studio like this:Warning 5 CA2202 : Microsoft.Usage : Object 'isolatedStorageFileStream' can be disposed more than once in method 'IsolatedStorageReader.ReadFromIsolatedStorage(string)'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object

Comment: Its just a fxcop warning. See this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3831947/25727

Comment: By the way, you can decorate the StreamReader class instance using [NonClosableStream class instance](http://code.google.com/p/sharpfilesystem/source/browse/trunk/SharpFileSystem/IO/NonClosableStream.cs) to prevent closing the stream by StreamReader class instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `using` keyword:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isolatedStorageFileStream = 
       new IsolatedStorageFileStream(
            strKey + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isoStore))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isolatedStorageFileStream))
{
    // Read a line from the file and add it to sb.
    strIsolatedStorageValue = reader.ReadLine();
}

return strIsolatedStorageValue;
```

`using` safely calls `Dispose` for you and you don't have to call it manually.

Answer (score 1):

The [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) automatically does try-finally for IDisposable (dispose if not null) for you.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isolatedStorageFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(strKey + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isoStore))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isolatedStorageFileStream))
    {
        string strIsolatedStorageValue = reader.ReadLine();
        return strIsolatedStorageValue;
    }
}
```