# Advise on code analysis, disposing more than once

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis

I'm just looking for some advice from someone more experienced than me really (wont be hard).

The following code...

```
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Installation));
        using (var sw = new StringWriter()) {
            using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw)) {
                serializer.Serialize(xw, Installation);
            }
            xmlResult = sw.ToString();
        }
```

has the following report in the code analysis...

> CA2202    Do not dispose objects multiple times   Object 'sw' can be
>   disposed more than once in method
>   'Views_Commissioning_installationSubsidyForm.SaveInstall(string)'. To
>   avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call
>   Dispose more than one time on an object.: Lines:
>   766   nc1_DealerPortal    installationSubsidyForm.aspx.cs 766

Can anyone explain how I'm disposing of 'sw' more than once? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is causing 'CA2202: Do not dispose objects multiple times' in this code and how can I refactor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706523/what-is-causing-ca2202-do-not-dispose-objects-multiple-times-in-this-code-and)

Answer (score 1):

`StringWriter` will be disposed by the `XmlWriter`, so by having 2 using statements it will get disposed twice change you code as below:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Installation));
var sw = new StringWriter()) 
using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw)) 
{
    serializer.Serialize(xw, Installation);
    xmlResult = sw.ToString();
}
```

Comment: why is it getting disposed by XmlWriter? Just some clarification for my self. (Maybe because of the fact, that sw is used to create a XmlWriter Object?)

Comment: so, if I use an object with another object that is instantiated within a using statement, the first object will also be disposed?

Comment: If `XmlWriter.Create()` fails, `sw` is not disposed. Code Analysis ought to complain about this one as well.

Comment: @Jeroen really? i thought it would be, because the using statement always uses a finally statement whether it errors or not, right? i thought that was the purpose of a using statement?

Comment: In the code @BenRobinson posted, `xw` is always disposed -- but `sw` isn't necessarily, because it's not in any `using` block. Rather than disposing twice, this code potentially does not dispose at all (of course, for `StringWriter`, this is of no practical importance).

Comment: @Stuart: no, not necessarily. There are some object in .NET and other libraries which take ownership of disposable objects you give them. But there is no guarantee of this. You need to check each case individually.