# Satisfying Code Analysing disposal rule with MemoryStream and CryptoStream

Tags: c#, memory, dispose

I have issues satisfying a code analysis rule for disposing a `MemoryStream` object.

This is my code right now:

```
byte[] bytes;
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
    cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}

bytes = stream.ToArray();
stream.Close();

return bytes;
```

This results in a warnings that the stream may be disposed *twice*, or may *not* be disposed (one warning for each).

I have also tried wrapping it into a `using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())` block. This results in the former warning.

And finally, removing the calls to `Close()` or `Dispose()` results in the latter warning.

Is there a way to satisfy both conditions? I assume the problem is an exception path that may close it, but I am not very familiar with how these classes work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally tend to suppress that rule in my source code if it fires because most objects do not have a problem being disposed twice.  But if you want to satisfy the Rule without suppressing you need to do this:

```
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        ICryptoTransform transform = null;

        MemoryStream stream = null;

        try
        {
            stream = new MemoryStream();
            MemoryStream tempStream = stream

            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                // set stream to null immediately so it doesn't get disposed by finally
                stream = null;

                cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                bytes = tempStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Dispose();
            }
        }

        return bytes;
```

Comment: Your code results in CA2202 Do not dispose objects multiple times..

Comment: Yep good catch.  I moved the steam = null statement to the first line of code inside the using statement and FXCop is happy.  I'm still not a fan of this Rule.

Comment: No warning, but you're now accessing `stream.ToArray()` after setting `stream = null`!

Comment: <Sigh>Yep, updated answer satisfy FXCop rule and not use Null objects</Sigh>

Comment: I see why you just suppress the rule now :)

Answer (score 2):

You can throw out all the streams by using

```
var bytes = transform.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

If there are no streams, you don't need worry about disposing them ;)

Comment: Real solution to the problem at hand (also question itself is duplicate of exactly the same sample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831676/ca2202-how-to-solve-this-case )

Answer (score 0):

When `CryptoStream` is disposed (when the `using` block ends), it calls `Close` on the `MemoryStream`, which calls `Dispose`.

So, you don't need to call `Dispose` (via `using`) or `Close` yourself. This way, `stream` only gets disposed exactly once.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
    cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    return stream.ToArray();            
}
```

Comment: That code can leave the MemoryStream undisposed if the CryptoStream constructor throws.

Comment: True, but it's not (IMO) a big deal. An empty MemoryStream is not large, and will still be GC'd eventually. And hopefully it is unlikely that CryptoStream's ctor throws. I don't see a way around it without triggering one of the code-analysis warnings.

Comment: I tend to suppress this rule and use 2 using statements.  But if you want not suppress and always dispose I updated my answer with the try/finally block to satisfy the rule.

Comment: @Blorgbeard `MemoryStream` have no-op `Dispose` by design since it has to keep internal buffer (managed byte array) alive for later calls to `ToArray`. So even not disposing "huge `MemoryStream`" is not an issue (nice to have correctly looking code, but no real difference).