# CA2202 nullify stream in example

Tags: c#

In documentation from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx) the following example is given for using streams.

```
Stream stream = null;  
try  
{  
    stream = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);  
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))  
    {  
        stream = null;  
        // Use the writer object...  
    }  
}  
finally  
{  
    if(stream != null)  
        stream.Dispose();  
}
```

Now i was wondering why would you set the `stream = null` before using the writer object?

Comment: To be able to use the variable in the finally section, I reckon. You have to define it outside the try block to use that way. __EDIT__ wrong alarm, the question does not refer to the very first line.

Comment: Probably for disposing and memory leaking of the stream. Normally you wrap the FileStream also in an using block

Comment: @vahdet that's not the question. He's talking about the line right over the comment, inside the `using` part

Comment: @JordyvanEijk While it should always be legal, they are trying to not double-dispose the `stream`. `StreamWriter` will already dispose it on closing.

Comment: But double-disposing it won't be a problem so it's unnecessary. Changing the outer try/finally to a using-block would be better though.

Comment: I would really suggest reading [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445790/how-to-satisfy-ca2202-do-not-dispose-objects-multiple-times). Just ignore the warning, it is useless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CA2202 is titled *Do not dispose objects multiple time*. I think that it is a stupid rule, because [the description of IDisposable.Dispose()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) is **very** clear on this:

> If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one. The object must not throw an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times.

so it is a rule about a non-problem, that causes the code to be more complex, for nothing! (note that I'm not the [only](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tilovell/2014/02/12/the-worst-code-analysis-rule-thats-recommended-ca2202/) and [only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3839419/613130) one that things this).

Basic information: the `StreamWriter` class will normally `Close()` (that is equivalent to `Dispose()` for `Stream` classes) on `Close()`/`Dispose()`, and it is said to take ownership of the base stream.

The basic problem is that the normal code

```
using (stream = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
}
```

will double `Close()` the `stream` (once from the `StreamWriter`, once from the external `using`), and this is frowned by the rule.

So we want to "manually" handle the `Dispose()` of the `stream` **if** `StreamWriter` hasn't taken ownership of the `stream`.

Now... "normal" exceptions can be thrown by the `FileStream` constructor (and in this case `stream` will be `null`, so nothing to clear), or in the `StreamWriter` constructor (and in this case `stream` will be not-`null` and `writer` will be `null`, so `stream` will need disposing, done in the `finally` block). Only asynchronous exceptions can be thrown between the end of the `StreamWriter` construction and the `stream = null;` but we will ignore them. Now... After the `StreamWriter` has been constructed and assigned to `writer`, `stream` can be marked as "we don't need to dispose it" (because the `StreamWriter` will close it for us), so `stream = null;`. Note that putting other lines between the `using ()` and the `stream = null;` could create other points where an exception is thrown, like:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))  
{ 
    if (something)
        throw new Exception();

    stream = null;  
    // Use the writer object...  
}
```

but this would cause a double `Dispose()` on the `FileStream`.