# How to fix Object 'oFs' can be disposed more than once in method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis, vs-community-edition

Code

```
public static void StrToFile(string value, string cFileName)
{
    if (File.Exists(cFileName) == true)
    {
        File.Delete(cFileName);
    }

    FileStream oFs = new FileStream(cFileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    StreamWriter oWriter = new StreamWriter(oFs);
    oWriter.Write(value);
    oWriter.Flush();
    oWriter.Close();
    oFs.Close();
}
```

causes in Visual Studio Community Edition code Analyze error at line         oFs.Close();

```
Warning CA2202  Object 'oFs' can be disposed more than once in method 'Core.StrToFile(string, string)'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on  an object.
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: Discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831676/ca2202-how-to-solve-this-case) may help you.

Comment: I though permission to use search before asking question is unlocked at 3475 points :)  - while your case may be different it is not yet clear in which way top search result for ca2202 did not help you. Please update your post to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you give ownership of the `FileStream` object to the `StreamWriter` object. Thus, when you close/dispose of the `StreamWriter` object, the `FileStream` object is closed/disposed of as well, and the analysis engine knows about this relationship.

Try using `using` instead, see if that works:

```
using (FileStream oFs = new FileStream(cFileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
using (StreamWriter oWriter = new StreamWriter(oFs))
{
    oWriter.Write(value);
    // oWriter.Flush();
}
```

If that doesn't work you may need to rewrite your code to more like this:

```
using (var oWriter = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(...)))
{
    oWriter.Write(value);
    // oWriter.Flush();
}
```

ie. pass the stream to the writer but then don't store a reference to it. Personally I don't like this variation since if there is a problem inside the constructor of `StreamWriter`, I'm not sure the `FileStream` object is correctly disposed of.

Comment: Nested usings has the same issue. Have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx where this exact example is described!